# Is it possible that Javascript keep same expression value?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if javascript calculate (again) same expressions as it encounters them  :

for example :

`alert(new Date().getTime()+1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1-new Date().getTime())`

`output : 0`

it's hard to test it like it but I thought that all the `+/-1` will take it some time ( a tick) so I could see a difference.

But the answer is 0.

So  ,

Is it zero because its just too fast or because JS treats the first new Date() as the same as the later one ?

Comment: Only took me 6 attempts when running that in the console to get `-1`

Comment: @MartinSmith well , I test just 3 ( in my stupidity). and later I duplicate the +-1 and i did see a difference.

Comment: It seems very unlikely to me that two calls to `new Date()` in the same line will be optimized into the same call as it is completely invalid to assume that two calls in the same line of code are supposed to occur at the same time. What if the called method includes a 20 second delay?

Comment: Btw, I am not sure the spec guarantees that the second call of `getTime ()` has to be performed *after* all the additions. It could be done before with the result being cached.

Comment: @JohnB that would be very interesting

Comment: @JohnB to some extent, yes. If an exception occurs during an addition (this _can_ happen), the second call may not happen unless the compiler proves the callee is without side-effects.

Comment: Well actually I think my first attempt I was lucky it took considerably more attempts to get the next `-1` but http://i.stack.imgur.com/PLGTI.png

Comment: @MartinSmith that means your computer is getting slower as time goes by .... :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GetTime()` returns the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch. Given that in **theory** an addition takes just one FLOP on a modern processor (which runs in the billions of FLOPS), I would say that it is extremely likely that the processor simply executes the entire statement in less than one millisecond.

Of course the way to really test this would be to run this billions of times in a loop and let the law of large numbers sort out the rest. To make things even easier, you could also try using alternating multiplication and division by an arbitrarily large number to make the execution take longer.

At any rate, keep in mind that in general, languages don't tend to optimise a function unless it always, or almost always makes sense to do so. In your specific case, how could the program reasonably assume that you aren't trying to measure how long the arithmetic takes? And what if you decomposed the single-line statement into several smaller statements? You would be doing the exact same thing... would it be reasonable in this case for the date/time function to act differently?

In short, I can think of many cases in which caching the date/time would cause serious problems in program execution. I can't imagine that the infinitesimally small performance boost provided by the caching would make up for them.

Comment: " you could also try using alternating multiplication and division by an arbitrarily large number to make the execution take longer." -- is there any machine where multiplication and division actually _is_ slow? I think the hardware implementation is pretty good nowadays. I'll run a perf, however.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken division is quite a slow operation in relative terms when compared to addition or subtraction. Multiplication not as much, but the point of the multiplication would be to nullify the division. You are still dealing in nanoseconds, but if the point is to drag the perf a bit then it may be a bit better way of doing things.

Comment: Here's the perf: http://jsperf.com/basic-ops; the results are not exactly conclusive, but yeah, division _is_ slow. It's even slower than modulo (O-0). I'm also surprised XOR is quite slow. It needs a few more re-runs.

Comment: @JanDvorak but XOR has to know both values in order to yield result. while or needs only the first `1`.... however why + is slower than `-` ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir My first test doesn't support + being faster than -. Also, I'm testing the bitwise operations, so in theory the CPU should always evaluate both arguments. I believe most measurement differences are merely errors in measurement.

Comment: @RoyiNamir so did I. I've run the test twice, and I keep getting "division slowest, modulo and XOR faster, the rest fastest".

Comment: ... with multiplication slightly slower than the rest of the fastest. The measured standard deviation is pretty high, however.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, 10 `+` operations and 10 `-` operations are probably not going to take a millisecond. You can test it like this:

```
var c = (new Date().getTime() + calc() - new Date().getTime());

function calc() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {}
    return 0;
}

console.log(c);
```

And you really are going to get an output that doesn't equal zero.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the crux of your question, which the other answers seem to be missing; no, it's not possible that the two calls to `new Date()` are optimized into the same thing. These two separate calls return distinct objects and for the engine to simply optimize the two distinct calls into one call would be completely invalid.

Consider, for example, if you had done this with a different method that returned a new `Date` object but this method included a 20 second delay in it (or an incremented return value each call) - the two `getTime` results should be thousands of ticks apart but your proposed "optimization" would cause them to return the same value.

What if the `Date()` function returned a random integer between 1 and 10,000?

There would be no way for the engine to know that the two calls should return the same value (which, incidentally, they shouldn't) without knowing what the returned values should be and, in order to know this, it would have to execute both methods anyway.

So, yes, it's because the calls are completed less than a millisecond apart.

Answer (score 1):

That will depend on the JavaScript engine. If the code is being pre-compiled, your +/- 1 calculation might be optimized away.

Comment: There is a limitation that adding and then subtracting one is not necessarily a no-op. For example, the input could be a string.

Comment: Well, but the compiler might somehow know that it is not.

Comment: It will, but you can't optimise away something that is not nothing. Part of it might be a NOP, but not the entire [+1-1] sequence.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, however, that `x - 1` is always equal to `x - 1 + 1 - 1`. There are plenty of corner cases, but at least `x-1` is always a number.